# React: The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component, TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typeerror

When I run my React app, I immediately get this error on the screen:

> Something went wrong
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

**In console I have:**

> The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component:
> in Connect(LocalizedComponent(Meta)) (created by AppComposer)
> in div (created by LocaleProvider)
> in LocaleProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
> in Connect(LocaleProvider) (created by Context.Consumer)
> in withRouter(Connect(LocaleProvider)) (created by AppComposer)
> in Router (created by AppComposer)
> in PersistGate (created by AppComposer)
> in Provider (created by AppComposer)
> in ErrorBoundary (created by AppComposer)
> in AppComposer (created by App)
> in Viewport (created by App)
> in div (created by Provider)
> in Provider (created by withWindowHandler(Provider))
> in withWindowHandler(Provider) (created by App)
> in App
> React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using
> the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.

It seems like a simple error but I can't find what causes the issue. I even searched for `.title` in the whole project and commented out each one of them, and I'm still getting the same error.

How can I find the piece of code which causes this error?

Comment: It's really hard to tell if you won't show the code.

Comment: @RyanLe it's a very big project so I can't upload the code here, but any advice on how to find that piece of code? From devtools or whatever.